# How to run iOS app in background to parse huge data API?

Tags: ios, swift, background, avaudioplayer

I have an application, it works in background mode and music is playing in background mode and while playing music background, we call API and parse 10,000 records data into local db. but it is not happening, Seems app crashing in the background.

Any suggestion are appreciated, If we are not hit any API and music is playing in the background but when API parsing happens, music and app are going to stop.

guard let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bird", ofType: "wav") else{return}

```
        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
        //try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.moviePlayback, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.moviePlayback, policy: AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        //try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        // Play audio forever by setting num of loops to -1
        self.player?.numberOfLoops = -1
        self.player?.volume = 0.01
        self.player?.prepareToPlay()
        self.player?.play()
```

Comment: Your use case is probably more suited for the new background processing task feature available in iOS 13, but that is still limited. iOS just doesn’t really  support large amounts of background work.

Comment: Yes, but when i have 10,000 records to parsing is very hard. so can we do special request to apple?

Comment: It sounds like you should be processing the records on a server somewhere or in the foreground.  I don't believe that there is any special permission Apple can grant, and it is unlikely that they would anyway.

Comment: Actually we hit api and api returns more than 10,000 records, while parsing those records to our local db will take time. so when user tap home button after some time app closing.

Comment: Your only real options are: 1. Ask them stay in the app until the download is complete (presumably his only happens on the first launch) 2. Resume the transfer from where it left off the next time the app returns to the foreground (possibly using background fetch to periodically fetch more records as well)

Comment: Well, we can do in midnight every day 1.45 when users do not use their app. our app plays a background silent music, so our app always will be in the background. but we are failing when parsing huge data.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to abuse background modes. You would be better off adapting your app to work with the system capabilities. Small downloads in the background via background fetch, for example. Delta support on your server so that you only need to download a large number of records once. Query the api in real time rather than having a local copy, have an api that returns all of the records in a zip file that you can retrieve via a background NSURLSession...

Comment: We download data from IoT device, it will not return small data, it always returns huge data and we need to parse it. because of IoT restrictions. Thank you for your glad help. we will consider your suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you need to prompt the user to remain in the app until the download is complete.

Comment: No, our app communicates with IoT device 24X7 and no one will touch our app. they just use it and customers know when they need to charge their iOS device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202767/discussion-between-paulw11-and-srinadh).

Answer (score 0):

There are very limited things you can do on background mode. You can use background app refresh to do limited task [apple docs for app refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) and [app background lifecycle method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time). There are great resources online on background app refresh. Even that will not work if user disabled background app refresh for the app.